# Issue with Blurring background of light box?

Tags: css, lightbox, blur

I am trying to create a blurred background effect to my lightbox and the filter blur css doesn't work, and instead it blurs the whole lightbox.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

My code is css no javascript, and it doesn't seem to work without blurring the foreground.

I've tried the blur filter, and I think this doesnt apply to the page once the lightbox image is clicked.

[Image showing blurred foreground and clear background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6LAmD.png)

```css
.container
{
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 6px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.small
{
  height: 180px;
  width: 320px;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  transition: .6s ease;
  filter: brightness(95%);
 }
.small:hover
{
  transform: scale(1.03);
  transition: .15s ease;
  opacity: 1;
  -moz-opacity: 100%;
  -webkit-opacity: 100%;
  filter: brightness(100%);
}
.lightbox
{
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.825);
  filter: blur(5px);
}
a div
{
 position: relative;
 margin: auto auto;
 text-align: center;
}

.lightbox:target
{
display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <a href="#img1"> 
<img class="small" src="http://www.arcadearchitecture.co.uk/img/projects/1.jpg">
</a>
 <a href="#img2"> 
<img class="small" src="http://www.arcadearchitecture.co.uk/img/projects/2.jpg">
</a>
 <a href="#img3"> 
<img class="small" src="http://www.arcadearchitecture.co.uk/img/projects/3.jpg">
</a>
  <a href="#img4"> 
<img class="small" src="http://www.arcadearchitecture.co.uk/img/projects/2.jpg">
</a>
  <a href="#img5"> 
<img class="small" src="http://www.arcadearchitecture.co.uk/img/projects/2.jpg">
</a>
  <a href="#img6"> 
<img class="small" src="http://www.arcadearchitecture.co.uk/img/projects/2.jpg">
</a>
  <a href="#img7"> 
<img class="small" src="http://www.arcadearchitecture.co.uk/img/projects/2.jpg">
</a>
  <a href="#img8"> 
<img class="small" src="http://www.arcadearchitecture.co.uk/img/projects/2.jpg">
</a>
  <a href="#img9"> 
<img class="small" src="http://www.arcadearchitecture.co.uk/img/projects/2.jpg">
</a>
  <a href="#img10"> 
<img class="small" src="http://www.arcadearchitecture.co.uk/img/projects/2.jpg">
</a>
  <a href="#img11"> 
<img class="small" src="http://www.arcadearchitecture.co.uk/img/projects/2.jpg">
</a>
  <a href="#img12"> 
<img class="small" src="http://www.arcadearchitecture.co.uk/img/projects/2.jpg">
</a>

  <a href="#_" class="lightbox" id="img1">
    <div>
      <img src="http://www.arcadearchitecture.co.uk/img/projects/1.jpg" width="67.5%"/>
      <h3>Extension | Barnsley _ December 2018</h3>
      <h6>- 12 -</h6>
      <h4>This traditional extension  in Barnsley redesigns the house layout from an existing small kitchen and seperate dining room to create a large open plan space.</h4>
    </div>
 </a>

  <a href="#_" class="lightbox" id="img2">
    <div>
      <img src="http://www.arcadearchitecture.co.uk/img/projects/2.jpg" width="67.5%"/>
      <h3>Extension | Barnsley _ December 2018</h3>
      <h6>- 11 -</h6>
      <h4>This contemporary dormer extension  in Barnsley converts the attic of a bungalow, creating two large bedrooms and a bathroom and is clad in dark grey uPVC panelling.</h4>
    </div>
 </a>

  <a href="#_" class="lightbox" id="img3">
    <div>
      <img src="http://www.arcadearchitecture.co.uk/img/projects/3.jpg" width="67.5%"/>
      <h3>Extension | Barnsley _ December 2018</h3>
      <h6>- 10 -</h6>
      <h4>This contemporary extension  in Barnsley has a white render finish around the corner of the front gable of a bungalow and this allows for the repositioning of the front door without the need for matching brickwork.</h4>
    </div>
 </a>

  <a href="#_" class="lightbox" id="img4">
    <div>
      <img src="http://www.arcadearchitecture.co.uk/img/projects/2.jpg" width="67.5%"/>
      <h3>Garden Room | Huddersfield _ December 2018</h3>
      <h6>- 9 -</h6>
      <h4>This contemporary garden room  in Huddersfield is clad in treated timber panels over a band of brickwork, it also has a set of bi-folding doors and full and mid height windows to allow for views of the garden and a space to put a desk against the wall.</h4>
    </div>
 </a>

  <a href="#_" class="lightbox" id="img5">
    <div>
      <img src="http://www.arcadearchitecture.co.uk/img/projects/2.jpg" width="67.5%"/>
      <h3>Extension | Leeds _ November 2018</h3>
      <h6>- 8 -</h6>
      <h4>This contemporary extension  in Leeds has a white render finish over a band of painted brickwork, it also has a corner of glazing to allow for views and access to the garden.</h4>
    </div>
 </a>

  <a href="#_" class="lightbox" id="img6">
    <div>
      <img src="http://www.arcadearchitecture.co.uk/img/projects/2.jpg" width="67.5%"/>
      <h3>Garden Room | Barnsley _ August 2018</h3>
      <h6>- 7 -</h6>
      <h4>This traditional garden room  in Barnsley was designed to replace existing outhouses and to make use of the sunlight to the rear of the garden. This project also involved the redesign of the parking to the rear of the property.</h4>
    </div>
 </a>

  <a href="#_" class="lightbox" id="img7">
    <div>
      <img src="http://www.arcadearchitecture.co.uk/img/projects/2.jpg" width="67.5%"/>
      <h3>Extension | Barnsley _ July 2018</h3>
      <h6>- 6 -</h6>
      <h4>This contemporary extension  in Barnsley has a cedar cladding section over a corner of glazing to allow for views of the garden, it also has a raised patio to allow for level access to a seating area.</h4>
    </div>
 </a>

  <a href="#_" class="lightbox" id="img8">
    <div>
      <img src="http://www.arcadearchitecture.co.uk/img/projects/2.jpg" width="67.5%"/>
      <h3>Extension | Barnsley _ June 2018</h3>
      <h6>- 5 -</h6>
      <h4>This traditional extension  in Barnsley is on the ground floor and extends the kitchen to create a open plan layout and also emulates the traditional style of the house.</h4>
    </div>
 </a>

  <a href="#_" class="lightbox" id="img9">
    <div>
      <img src="http://www.arcadearchitecture.co.uk/img/projects/2.jpg" width="67.5%"/>
      <h3>Visual | Huddersfield _ May 2018</h3>
      <h6>- 4 -</h6>
      <h4>This visual ‍ was created to depict the rear of a traditional new build home, that has a contemporary extension in Huddersfield. The house was designed by Northern Design Partnership in Holmfirth.</h4>
    </div>
 
  </a>
  <a href="#_" class="lightbox" id="img10">
    <div>
      <img src="http://www.arcadearchitecture.co.uk/img/projects/2.jpg" width="67.5%"/>
      <h3>Garden Room | Holmfirth _ March 2018</h3>
      <h6>- 3 -</h6>
      <h4>This contemporary garden room  in Holmfirth was designed to provide a space for guests to stay in while also having a small shower room behind the stone cladding.</h4>
    </div>
 
  </a>
  <a href="#_" class="lightbox" id="img11">
    <div>
      <img src="http://www.arcadearchitecture.co.uk/img/projects/2.jpg" width="67.5%"/>
      <h3>Porch | Huddersfield _ June 2017</h3>
      <h6>- 2 -</h6>
      <h4>This traditional stone clad porch  in Huddersfield was designed and had building drawings produced by us. It emulates the traditional style of the property and uses the same materials.</h4>
    </div>
 
  </a>
  <a href="#_" class="lightbox" id="img12">
    <div>
      <img src="http://www.arcadearchitecture.co.uk/img/projects/2.jpg" width="67.5%"/>
      <h3>Garden Room | Barnsley _ July 2016</h3>
      <h6>- 1 -</h6>
      <h4>These visuals depict the interior of a contemporary garden room  in Barnsley and it provides a space for guests to stay in while also doubling up as a painting room.</h4>
    </div>
 
  </a>
  </div>
```

Comment: Please edit your code to link your pictures absololutely for us to see the behaviour.

Comment: Thanks ive updated the code.

Comment: So what are you trying to blur? The image (?) because I'm not seeing a background in place that *can* be blurred.

Comment: image attached.

Comment: Hi Paulie,Ive attached the image to show what i mean

Comment: @timharrymurphy this isn't lightbox, but it's an example of blurring background (an old sample) I haven't got time to focus on your question now, but it might help https://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/0L69gj3m/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Edit

#### Added after asker made clear that he wanted something different

If you want to have the full background blurred you need to change the HTML structure. Since you react on the `:target` pseudo-element to show the lightbox, you need to have the elements react to the shown lightbox follow the lightbox to make use of the [general siblings combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator) `~`. So all of the lightboxes must precede the `.container` element and that `.container` element is blurred, if any `.lightbox` before it is targeted.

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 6px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: filter .3s linear;
}

.small {
  height: 180px;
  width: 320px;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  filter: brightness(95%);
}

.small:hover {
  transform: scale(1.03);
  transition: 0.15s ease;
  opacity: 1;
  -moz-opacity: 100%;
  -webkit-opacity: 100%;
  filter: brightness(100%);
}

.lightbox {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.825);
}
.lightbox:target {
  display: flex;
}
.lightbox:target ~ .container {
  transition: filter 1s linear;
  filter: blur(5px);
}

a div {
  position: relative;
  margin: auto auto;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<a href="#_" class="lightbox" id="img1">
  <div>
    <img src="http://www.arcadearchitecture.co.uk/img/projects/1.jpg" width="67.5%" />
    <h3>Extension | Barnsley _ December 2018</h3>
    <h6>- 12 -</h6>
    <h4>This traditional extension  in Barnsley redesigns the house layout from an existing small kitchen and seperate dining room to create a large open plan space.</h4>
  </div>
</a>

<a href="#_" class="lightbox" id="img2">
  <div>
    <img src="http://www.arcadearchitecture.co.uk/img/projects/2.jpg" width="67.5%" />
    <h3>Extension | Barnsley _ December 2018</h3>
    <h6>- 11 -</h6>
    <h4>This contemporary dormer extension  in Barnsley converts the attic of a bungalow, creating two large bedrooms and a bathroom and is clad in dark grey uPVC panelling.</h4>
  </div>
</a>

<a href="#_" class="lightbox" id="img3">
  <div>
    <img src="http://www.arcadearchitecture.co.uk/img/projects/3.jpg" width="67.5%" />
    <h3>Extension | Barnsley _ December 2018</h3>
    <h6>- 10 -</h6>
    <h4>This contemporary extension  in Barnsley has a white render finish around the corner of the front gable of a bungalow and this allows for the repositioning of the front door without the need for matching brickwork.</h4>
  </div>
</a>

<a href="#_" class="lightbox" id="img4">
  <div>
    <img src="http://www.arcadearchitecture.co.uk/img/projects/2.jpg" width="67.5%" />
    <h3>Garden Room | Huddersfield _ December 2018</h3>
    <h6>- 9 -</h6>
    <h4>This contemporary garden room  in Huddersfield is clad in treated timber panels over a band of brickwork, it also has a set of bi-folding doors and full and mid height windows to allow for views of the garden and a space to put a desk against
      the wall.</h4>
  </div>
</a>

<a href="#_" class="lightbox" id="img5">
  <div>
    <img src="http://www.arcadearchitecture.co.uk/img/projects/2.jpg" width="67.5%" />
    <h3>Extension | Leeds _ November 2018</h3>
    <h6>- 8 -</h6>
    <h4>This contemporary extension  in Leeds has a white render finish over a band of painted brickwork, it also has a corner of glazing to allow for views and access to the garden.</h4>
  </div>
</a>


<div class="container">
  <a href="#img1"> 
    <img class="small" src="http://www.arcadearchitecture.co.uk/img/projects/1.jpg">
  </a>
  <a href="#img2"> 
    <img class="small" src="http://www.arcadearchitecture.co.uk/img/projects/2.jpg">
  </a>
  <a href="#img3"> 
    <img class="small" src="http://www.arcadearchitecture.co.uk/img/projects/3.jpg">
  </a>
  <a href="#img4"> 
    <img class="small" src="http://www.arcadearchitecture.co.uk/img/projects/2.jpg">
  </a>
  <a href="#img5"> 
    <img class="small" src="http://www.arcadearchitecture.co.uk/img/projects/2.jpg">
  </a>


</div>
```

### Backup

This is not, what the asker wanted
You just have to restrict the blur filter to the image.
So instead

```
.lightbox {
  /* ... */
  filter: blur(5px);
}
```

do this

```
.lightbox img {
  /* ... */
  filter: blur(5px);
}
```

```css
.container
{
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 6px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.small
{
  height: 180px;
  width: 320px;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  transition: .6s ease;
  filter: brightness(95%);
 }
.small:hover
{
  transform: scale(1.03);
  transition: .15s ease;
  opacity: 1;
  -moz-opacity: 100%;
  -webkit-opacity: 100%;
  filter: brightness(100%);
}
.lightbox
{
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.825);
}
.lightbox img {
  filter: blur(5px);
}
a div
{
 position: relative;
 margin: auto auto;
 text-align: center;
}

.lightbox:target
{
display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <a href="#img1"> 
<img class="small" src="http://www.arcadearchitecture.co.uk/img/projects/1.jpg">
</a>
 <a href="#img2"> 
<img class="small" src="http://www.arcadearchitecture.co.uk/img/projects/2.jpg">
</a>
 <a href="#img3"> 
<img class="small" src="http://www.arcadearchitecture.co.uk/img/projects/3.jpg">
</a>
  <a href="#img4"> 
<img class="small" src="http://www.arcadearchitecture.co.uk/img/projects/2.jpg">
</a>
  <a href="#img5"> 
<img class="small" src="http://www.arcadearchitecture.co.uk/img/projects/2.jpg">
</a>
  <a href="#img6"> 
<img class="small" src="http://www.arcadearchitecture.co.uk/img/projects/2.jpg">
</a>
  <a href="#img7"> 
<img class="small" src="http://www.arcadearchitecture.co.uk/img/projects/2.jpg">
</a>
  <a href="#img8"> 
<img class="small" src="http://www.arcadearchitecture.co.uk/img/projects/2.jpg">
</a>
  <a href="#img9"> 
<img class="small" src="http://www.arcadearchitecture.co.uk/img/projects/2.jpg">
</a>
  <a href="#img10"> 
<img class="small" src="http://www.arcadearchitecture.co.uk/img/projects/2.jpg">
</a>
  <a href="#img11"> 
<img class="small" src="http://www.arcadearchitecture.co.uk/img/projects/2.jpg">
</a>
  <a href="#img12"> 
<img class="small" src="http://www.arcadearchitecture.co.uk/img/projects/2.jpg">
</a>

  <a href="#_" class="lightbox" id="img1">
    <div>
      <img src="http://www.arcadearchitecture.co.uk/img/projects/1.jpg" width="67.5%"/>
      <h3>Extension | Barnsley _ December 2018</h3>
      <h6>- 12 -</h6>
      <h4>This traditional extension  in Barnsley redesigns the house layout from an existing small kitchen and seperate dining room to create a large open plan space.</h4>
    </div>
 </a>

  <a href="#_" class="lightbox" id="img2">
    <div>
      <img src="http://www.arcadearchitecture.co.uk/img/projects/2.jpg" width="67.5%"/>
      <h3>Extension | Barnsley _ December 2018</h3>
      <h6>- 11 -</h6>
      <h4>This contemporary dormer extension  in Barnsley converts the attic of a bungalow, creating two large bedrooms and a bathroom and is clad in dark grey uPVC panelling.</h4>
    </div>
 </a>

  <a href="#_" class="lightbox" id="img3">
    <div>
      <img src="http://www.arcadearchitecture.co.uk/img/projects/3.jpg" width="67.5%"/>
      <h3>Extension | Barnsley _ December 2018</h3>
      <h6>- 10 -</h6>
      <h4>This contemporary extension  in Barnsley has a white render finish around the corner of the front gable of a bungalow and this allows for the repositioning of the front door without the need for matching brickwork.</h4>
    </div>
 </a>

  <a href="#_" class="lightbox" id="img4">
    <div>
      <img src="http://www.arcadearchitecture.co.uk/img/projects/2.jpg" width="67.5%"/>
      <h3>Garden Room | Huddersfield _ December 2018</h3>
      <h6>- 9 -</h6>
      <h4>This contemporary garden room  in Huddersfield is clad in treated timber panels over a band of brickwork, it also has a set of bi-folding doors and full and mid height windows to allow for views of the garden and a space to put a desk against the wall.</h4>
    </div>
 </a>

  <a href="#_" class="lightbox" id="img5">
    <div>
      <img src="http://www.arcadearchitecture.co.uk/img/projects/2.jpg" width="67.5%"/>
      <h3>Extension | Leeds _ November 2018</h3>
      <h6>- 8 -</h6>
      <h4>This contemporary extension  in Leeds has a white render finish over a band of painted brickwork, it also has a corner of glazing to allow for views and access to the garden.</h4>
    </div>
 </a>

  <a href="#_" class="lightbox" id="img6">
    <div>
      <img src="http://www.arcadearchitecture.co.uk/img/projects/2.jpg" width="67.5%"/>
      <h3>Garden Room | Barnsley _ August 2018</h3>
      <h6>- 7 -</h6>
      <h4>This traditional garden room  in Barnsley was designed to replace existing outhouses and to make use of the sunlight to the rear of the garden. This project also involved the redesign of the parking to the rear of the property.</h4>
    </div>
 </a>

  <a href="#_" class="lightbox" id="img7">
    <div>
      <img src="http://www.arcadearchitecture.co.uk/img/projects/2.jpg" width="67.5%"/>
      <h3>Extension | Barnsley _ July 2018</h3>
      <h6>- 6 -</h6>
      <h4>This contemporary extension  in Barnsley has a cedar cladding section over a corner of glazing to allow for views of the garden, it also has a raised patio to allow for level access to a seating area.</h4>
    </div>
 </a>

  <a href="#_" class="lightbox" id="img8">
    <div>
      <img src="http://www.arcadearchitecture.co.uk/img/projects/2.jpg" width="67.5%"/>
      <h3>Extension | Barnsley _ June 2018</h3>
      <h6>- 5 -</h6>
      <h4>This traditional extension  in Barnsley is on the ground floor and extends the kitchen to create a open plan layout and also emulates the traditional style of the house.</h4>
    </div>
 </a>

  <a href="#_" class="lightbox" id="img9">
    <div>
      <img src="http://www.arcadearchitecture.co.uk/img/projects/2.jpg" width="67.5%"/>
      <h3>Visual | Huddersfield _ May 2018</h3>
      <h6>- 4 -</h6>
      <h4>This visual ‍ was created to depict the rear of a traditional new build home, that has a contemporary extension in Huddersfield. The house was designed by Northern Design Partnership in Holmfirth.</h4>
    </div>
 
  </a>
  <a href="#_" class="lightbox" id="img10">
    <div>
      <img src="http://www.arcadearchitecture.co.uk/img/projects/2.jpg" width="67.5%"/>
      <h3>Garden Room | Holmfirth _ March 2018</h3>
      <h6>- 3 -</h6>
      <h4>This contemporary garden room  in Holmfirth was designed to provide a space for guests to stay in while also having a small shower room behind the stone cladding.</h4>
    </div>
 
  </a>
  <a href="#_" class="lightbox" id="img11">
    <div>
      <img src="http://www.arcadearchitecture.co.uk/img/projects/2.jpg" width="67.5%"/>
      <h3>Porch | Huddersfield _ June 2017</h3>
      <h6>- 2 -</h6>
      <h4>This traditional stone clad porch  in Huddersfield was designed and had building drawings produced by us. It emulates the traditional style of the property and uses the same materials.</h4>
    </div>
 
  </a>
  <a href="#_" class="lightbox" id="img12">
    <div>
      <img src="http://www.arcadearchitecture.co.uk/img/projects/2.jpg" width="67.5%"/>
      <h3>Garden Room | Barnsley _ July 2016</h3>
      <h6>- 1 -</h6>
      <h4>These visuals depict the interior of a contemporary garden room  in Barnsley and it provides a space for guests to stay in while also doubling up as a painting room.</h4>
    </div>
 
  </a>
  </div>
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response,

Comment: This blurs the image and not the background of the image

Comment: Your question was misleading. I thought you wanted to do exactly that. I added a change to achieve what I think you want to achieve

Comment: Thanks, i have tried this and it doesnt seem to change it, can you explain what you mean by changing the html structure? have you changed the html code?

Comment: I have added some explanation before my snippet

Comment: many thanks for the help, seems like a lot of work to change the html of the page so I will stick to what i have.

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that, but you have no other chance without using JavaScript